# Spark-SQL- managed tables needs & features

Tags: apache-spark

I have below questions on spark managed tables.

1. Does Spark tables/view are for long term persistent storage? If Yes, when we create a table, where does physical data gets stored?
2. What is the exact purpose of spark tables as opposed to dataframe?
3. If we create a spark tables for temporary purpose, are we not filling up disk space that otherwise used for Spark compute needs in jobs?

Comment: have u read any freely available texts on the subjects?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please, try to ask one question at the time, and remember to ask questions that can be answered, ideally in a straightforward manner.

Answer (score 0):

1. Spark view (Temp view and Global Temp View) are not for long term persistent storage. they will only alive till your spark session is active. and when you write data in one of your spark/hive table using save() method it will write the data in spark_warehouse folder based on your system path of spark.
2. DataFrames are more of a programmatically designed but if their are developer who is not comfortable with programming languages like Scala, Python and R so for them spark exposed the SQL based API. But under the hood all of them have same performance because they all need to pass through the same Catalyst Optimizer.

3.Spark manages all the tables in it's catalog and catalog is connected with it's metastore. Now whenever we create any temp table it will copy it's data to the catalog or in spark_warehouse folder rather it will make a reference to that dataframe from which we are creating the tempview. when this spark session will end this temporary views are also deleted from catalog information.